# Alert Boxes Adobe Flex mobile - Searching - Block until get response

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

Im creating an application on Adobe Flex mobile (Blackberry playbook to be exact). Im designing an app that has a search function that makes a simple HTTP request to a server and waits for a response...

When the user clicks on search, how do I create an alert box that says "Searching..." and doesn't disappear until we get an HTTP response?

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add event listener to HTTP object that listen the response

then show the dialog on start search and hide it when response listener is called

```
        private var service:HTTPService 

        public function useHttpService(parameters:Object):void {
            service = new HTTPService();
            service.destination = "sampleDestination";
            service.method = "POST";
            service.addEventListener("result", httpResult);
            service.addEventListener("fault", httpFault);
            service.send(parameters);
        }

        public function httpResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
            var result:Object = event.result;
        //in your case show the dialog on search click and hide the dialog here. 
        }

        public function httpFault(event:FaultEvent):void {
            var faultstring:String = event.fault.faultString;
            Alert.show(faultstring);

        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```